# AS400 RPGLE PROGRAM

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

i am trying to delete a record from physical file PFILE which has no keyed field but i don't know why statements in if clause are not working even though i have a record with id=123

```
0001.00 fPFILE     UF   E             DISK            
0002.00 DID               S              8P 0         
0003.00 c                   read      rec             
0004.00 c                   eval      ID=123          
0005.00 c     ID            CHAIN     PFILE           
0006.00 C     EMPID         DSPLY                     
0007.00 c                   IF        %FOUND()        
0008.00 C     EMPNAME       DSPLY                     
0009.00 c                   DELETE    REC             
0010.00 C     'DELETED'     DSPLY                     
0011.00 c                   ELSE                      
0012.00 c     'NOTFOUND'    DSPLY                     
0013.00 c                   ENDIF                     
0014.00 C                   SETON
```

This is my PFILE

```
0001.00                 R REC                                                
0002.00                   EMPID          7P 0                                
0003.00                   EMPNAME       15A
```

Comment: Can you please wrap your code in a code block so it is easier to read? Have you tried using the file record format with the delete command instead of the file name? And lastly it would help if you gave us a joblog message at least of what is failing. Otherwise this post has no significant to the next person that has this type of problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Rant:**

- STOP USING FIXED FORMAT RPGLE
- STOP USING DDS

You are giving me Eye Cancer.

**Answer:**

The %chain operation code is used to access records by either "Key" or "RRN"

You have confused the ID column in your table with the "RRN"

[IBM Knowledge Center - CHAIN (Random Retrieval from a File)](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzasd/zzchain.htm)

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what is the alternative to DDS? (SQL scripts to generate tables?)

Comment: According to Birgitta Hauser ==> BTW all new "physical" and "logical" files, respective tables and indexes should be created with SQL, because DDS is "stabilized" there will be no future enhancement. All new development is done in SQL ==>  Refer to http://www.rpgpgm.com/2015/01/reading-sql-table-in-rpg.html or http://xcasefori.com/modernize.html?utm_source=MC%20Press&utm_medium=article&utm_campaign=online%20publication

Comment: Also According to Briggitta ==> The main reasion to move from DDS to DDL is, DDS is STABILIZED, that means will not be enhanced anymore.
Since Release V4R5 all new development is solely done for SQL ==> Refer to http://www.code400.com/forum/forum/iseries-programming-languages/dds/9551-dds-or-ddl

Comment: Thanks for the links!! I was shown how to generate DDS files and compile them to generate tables, but found in System i Navigator "generate SQL" for the tables and have since then been trying to make my own tables using SQL instead...!

Comment: Good job Cody using sql to create tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "chain" to access a file with the key, or with the record number.

```
fPFILE     UF   E             DISK            
DID               S              8P 0         

 /free
   id = 123;
   chain id rec;
   if %found;
      delete rec;
   endif;
   *inlr = '1';
   return;
 /end-free
```

Comment: you can only chain the first 64k records with chain.  With SQL you can use the RRN to 10 digitis.

Comment: On AS/400 there was no 64K limit on RRN. The original RPG User manual stated that the RRN field must be long enough to hold the largest record number. When using a record address file in S/36 mode you had a 3 byte signed integer for RRN, and in AS/400 mode you had a 4 byte signed integer.  That means the S/36 could access 16M records and the AS/400 could access 2G records by RRN. Even with CHAIN.

Answer (score 1):

To chain to a file you have to tell the compiler it is keyed.  There should be a K in the file specification.

```
0001.00 fPFILE     UF   E             DISK            
0002.00 DID               S              8P 0         
0003.00 c                   read      rec             
0004.00 c                   eval      ID=123
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used RRN to "CHAIN" subfile recs.  As stated above, you can create a logical with a key over a non-keyed file. If you have a specific value (ID) that you know you want to delete, you can also set a READ loop and test the ID for matching values. IF not found, ITER.  if found, DELETE. 
this is basic stuff, green screen fixed position code aka old school. 
(without a chain to a logical).

```
move *OFF *IN30

*IN30  DOWEQ *OFF

READ PFILE    30

*IN30  IFEQ *ON

LEAVE

ENDIF

fILEid  IFNE COMPAREid

ITER

ENDIF

 DELET PFILEREC  

 LEAVE

ENDDO
```

Answer (score 1):

Your F-spec does not say the file has a key, so ID=123 means record #123 in PFILE.  If PFILE does not contain at least 123 records, the chain will fail.

Comment: And if your file has more than 123 records, then you could be deleting the wrong record!

Answer (score 0):

To read any data from file based any field of physical file, you must have key in physical file or create logical file with key field. Then you can use chain and %found() combination.

Chill
Sudeep

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised this even compiles. I would do a rename(rec:arec), then delete arec.

If that doesn't work, do you have FA or another way to access the physical file? If so, find the record and delete it manually if it's an emergency.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a key to your physical file. See line 6 below. If you want it unique, see line 1 below. Next, tell your RPG program in the file spec that the file is keyed by using the "K".

Then, no nead for a read. Chaining the file with the key will go directly to the record for delete, no need to read. Lastly, I always put the file name in the function, for example %found(file). You can certainly omit it, but I have had strange results sometimes when not including it, mostly when dealing with readc on subfiles.

// The file

```
.....A..........T.Name++++++RLen++TDpB......Functions++++++++++++++++++
0000.01      A                                      UNIQUE                     
0000.02      A          R PFILEREC                                             
0000.03      A            EMPID          7P 0                                  
0000.04      A            EMPNAME       15A                                    
0000.05       * SET A KEY FOR THE FILE                                         
0000.06      A          K EMPID                                                

// the program

     FMT FX FFilename++IPEASF.....L.....A.Device+.Keywords
0000.03 fpFile     uf   e           k disk            
0000.04 f                                             
0000.05 d id              s              8p 0 Inz(123)
0000.06 d                                             
0000.07 c     key           klist                     
0000.08 c                   kfld                    id
0000.09 c                                             
0000.10 c     key           chain     pFile           
0000.11 c                   if        %found(pFile)   
0000.12 c                   delete    pFileRec        
0000.13 c                   endif                     
0000.14 c                                             
0000.15 c                   eval      *inlr = *on     
0000.16 c
```